# My nano editor can't read tags?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, nano

I normally use nano edit, however, today when I open it, it didn't show "<>" and character next to it. I have reinstalled Ubuntu and the problem is still there.

In the image below it doesn't show "<role" for example:

[image: Screenshot showing error]

I know they are missing because when I add a comment "<role" shows up:

[image: Screenshot showing expected output]

Comment: How did you verify that `<role` is supposed to be in the file? Unless you have some custom configurations for `nano`, it will just display everything in the file.

Comment: @Paul When i add comment it show up https://ibb.co/rm83v7P

Comment: Have you configured anything in `/etc/nanorc` or `~/.nanorc`?

Comment: No, i didn't config any thing in there

Comment: re-installation sounds extreme, given the huge number of other text editing  software you could install and use. Is this a Windows Linux Subsystem?

Comment: @j0h yes i use wsl version 2

Comment: vim can't read that too ;(

Comment: I suspect WLS is missing the proper fonts or has something that bash cant display properly. what font is bash using? I havent used WLS, but I imagine its probably a right click properties, then goto fonts or something like that. you might need to install fonts.

Comment: I dont think its font 's problem because .json file and  .js working well and file using tag <> like xml and html got error

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the contents directly from the editor? I suspect it's a color issue, where its black text on black background.

Comment: @ArturMeinild OH you 're right it has the same color with background, but how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we have established that you have black text on black background, I imagine there are 2 possible solutions:

1. Either it's the color settings in your terminal application
2. Or a problem with the color settings in your `<fileformat>.nanorc` files

For 1, you have to explore the settings of your terminal application, and see it the colors are defined in such a way that one of the foreground colors are set to black.

For 2, go to this directory:

```
cd /usr/share/nano/
```

Here you will find a number of syntax highlighting files, especially check out `html.nanorc` and `xml.nanorc`.

By adjusting these, you should be able to test if you can set different colors, so that it works for you.

Please try the above 2 things, I'm pretty sure at least one of them can fix your issue.

Comment: Fixed, Many Thanks! you 're so brilliant

Comment: I'm happy it worked out for you. Cheers!

Comment: you can start nano with no syntax highlighting or colouring by using `nano -Ynone [whatever]`